# access django session from a decorator

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-sessions

I have a decorator that I use for my views @valid_session

```
from django.http import Http404

def valid_session(the_func):
"""
function to check if the user has a valid session
"""
def _decorated(*args, **kwargs):        
    if ## check if username is in the request.session:
        raise Http404('not logged in.')
    else:
        return the_func(*args, **kwargs)
return _decorated
```

I would like to access my session in my decoartor. When user is logged in, I put the username in my session.

Answer (score 4):

Will something like the following solve your problem:

```
def valid_session(func):
    def decorated(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request.session
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Comment: @ed1t, have you put username to request.session before reading it?

Comment: @ed1t Is `django.contrib.sessions` installed? What about the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list in your settings.py? Does it have something like a session middleware in it?

Answer (score 1):

The view function takes the request as the first parameter, so the decorator will receive it as its first parameter as well.  You can pull the session out of it with just request.session.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the request (or just the session) in as a [parameter to the decorator](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845). I just don't know how to get at it to pass it in. I was trying to figure out something similar last night.